# Angular CLI Generate files with 4 spaces instead of 2

Tags: angular, angular-cli, indentation

Simple problem I'm trying to solve, but haven't found a solution yet. We're using the latest version of Angular and the Angular CLI, but when we use the cli to generate files like components, it always uses the 2 space indentation. We are a 4 space indentation shop, so manually changing the files after every generation is quite frustrating. It looks like there used to be some kind of --fixLint flag, but it's either deprecated or not working anymore.
Has anybody gotten the indentations working correctly for 4 spaces, and how did you do it?

Comment: why don't you set indent_size = 4 in your .editorconfig file?

Comment: @playerone, that's exactly what I have, but generated files still have 2 spaces. I can open each created file and have VS Code format the document based off the editorconfig, but that's a manual process for each file that I don't want to have to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid this is not supported. See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9953

Comment: Well darn. Not the answer I was hoping for  Is what it is I guess. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Like [@tine2k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/936416/tine2k) said it is not possible, but there is a lesser know workaround to format all files at once

1. Install prettier as `npm` dependency globally (instead of VS Code extension) (-g for global)

```bash
npm install -g prettier
```

2. Edit `.editorconfig` file set `indent_size` as `4`

```bash
indent_size = 4
```

3. config prettier for the current repo (optional)

> create new file `.prettierignore` and add

```bash
.angular
.vscode
node_modules
```

> This is to ignore these folders from getting formatted (by default `node_modules` is ignored, but added just for safety)

4. Run formatter

```bash
prettier -w .
```

> `-w` writes formatted code to file, if not provided, it just prints to terminal

Newly generated components doesn't seem to obey the `.editorconfig` either, so run prettier again after generating components as well

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the **.editorconfig** file in the root directory of your project.
   Add or modify the indent_size property to have a value of 4. This sets the indentation size to four spaces.

**.editorconfig**:

```
...
indent_size = 4
...
```

2. Open the **tslint.json** file in the root directory of your project. Find the "indent" rule and update its options to use tabs and a size
   of four.

**tslint.json:**

```
"indent": {
   ...
   "options": ["tabs", 4],
   ...
}
```

Then you can use Prettier to format your code automatically.

1. Install Prettier as a dev dependency by running the following command in your project directory:

(Not installed in global)

```
npm i -D prettier
```

4. Once Prettier is installed, you can execute it through the Node.js modules. Use the following command to format your project's files:

```
npx prettier -w .
```